# How to restore an ESXi host that lost it's management access

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

An ESXi 5.5.0 build 2068190 host (Dell T110 ii) lost it's management access. The management NIC is also shared with the VM guests and they work so it's not a bad embedded NIC. The static address on the host now shows 0.0.0.0 and it won't accept manually updating it. There is one active guest that automatically starts on boot which is the domain controller and runs DHCP and DNS. This VM is crucial so before doing anything I would like to be able to export a backup of it from the CLI directly from the physical host to a external USB hard drive since the management NIC can't ping out or see anything there is no way to specify a network destination. After verifying the backup, then I'd like to try repairing the host or rebuild if absolutely necessary.

Comment: First make sure that the IP address of the ESXi is unique, and not for example been given out by DHCP.

Comment: Yes, it was statically configured, however when it lost it's IP it just shows 0.0.0.0 as the static address and it won't let apply any open IP as it keeps reverting to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Can you check whether DHCP or static configuration of IP is enabled?

Comment: `The static address on the host now shows 0.0.0.0 and it won't accept manually updating it` - What do you mean by that? Are you trying to edit the ip address of the Management Network from the physical console?

Comment: I set it to static and give it a valid IP and it reverts to 0.0.0.0, I've tried resetting the network as well but it does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, from the physical console.

Comment: How is ESXi installed? Is it on local disk or something like USB/SD card?

Comment: It's installed on the local disk